Looking for a manga or manhwa where mc was on an adventurer test and saves a girl by jumping off a cliff and she teaches him how to fight
If I remember right, the mc was on an adventurer test, then saw an injured girl and a lightning tiger or puma, and saves the girl and himself by jumping off a cliff. And because she is injured, she teaches him how to fight monsters and I think she tells him that she goes to an adventurer school. When she was healed, she went back to her school and when the mc got to the top, he meets bandits or hunters, defeats them, then goes on a journey to her school.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Was it in colour or black-and-white?

I think it was colored but i might be wrong
